# Cat5 to Cat5e to Cat6

Tags: cat5e, cat6, cat5

So my CNC has cat5 ran throughout the interior body, on the exterior of the machine it has a cat5 connection. I plugged that into a converter extension to cat5e. I connected my 5ft cat5e to a switch. From the switch I have cat6 to my router. Is there an issue with this? Because, I cannot transfer files to my CNC router. All using rj45 besides the cat5

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, as long as you are not approaching the limits of CAT5-6 cable (length), you shouldn't have any issues.  If it all worked using CAT5 cable previously, and you simply added CAT6... you should see no additional issues.  CAT5e and CAT6 cable are rated for lower interference, and better conduction, and would not cause problems.  It is more likely that your termination of the cables is faulty.  CAT6 cable cannot be used with CAT5/5e cable ends.  Sometimes you might get lucky... but it would be unreliable at best.

Comment: "CAT6 cable cannot be used with CAT5/5e cable ends" Sure it can. It's just not cat6 anymore, and is effectively cat5. Some cat6 cable with larger conductors and thicker insulation would have a hard time getting stuffed into a cat5 head, but it's doable.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M Actually, no.  It doesn't fit correctly.  CAT5 cable ends expect the wire to be significantly smaller than what CAT6 is.  You're likely to make a very poor connection with CAT6 wire... and likely would cut/break solid-core wire... or cause stranded wire to make intermittent connections... 

it may *work* for the moment... but definitely unreliably at best.  (as I have previously said)